# Pyemu - cannot use PEPyEmu() module, Python

Tags: malware, unpacking, python, upx

I want to run code from Gray Hat Python book for upx_unpacker. I have downloaded PyEmu, but when I run script I got this error:
`AttributeError: PEPyEmu instance has no attribute 'load'`

My script use PEPyEmu this way:

```
sys.path.append("C:\PyEmu\pyemu-master")
sys.path.append("C:\PyEmu\pyemu-master\\lib")
from PyEmu import PEPyEmu

exename = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]

emu = PEPyEmu()
if exename:
    if not emu.load(exename):
        print "[!] Problem loading %s" %exename
        sys.exit(2)
else:
    print "[!] Blank filename specified"
    sys.exit(3)
```

This code is same as in the book, but it does not work. I use Python 2.7.14, `Pyemu` from https://github.com/codypierce/pyemu
Anyone know how to resolve it and run this script? I didn't find any help in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Please check example usage in https://github.com/codypierce/pyemu/blob/master/examples/pepyemu.py. It looks like load method is not implemented.
Based on example usage it's required to load PE file manually.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But I do not understand what should be pass as a second argument, and thats why I got errors when tried to run this script on my exe.

Comment: That example script allows to start execution from choosen address. For start I would use what's stored and presented as entrypoint.